# Why my products don't go out of stock when qty = 0 in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, stock

I tried to make a order with a product with an inventory of 1.

When the order is completed, the stock is 0. It's ok.

However, the `Stock Availability` is set to "`In stock`". And the option `Qty for Item's Status to become Out of Stock` is set to `0` too.

Do you have any ideas? I don't understand.

**Edit, here is the config:**

**System > Configuration > Catalog > Inventory (Global) :**
[image]

**Product > Inventory (Product specific)**
[image]

Comment: @chris_mcclellan, any constructive comment?

Comment: You're right.  Sorry.  Just too many problems to count.

Comment: Configuration seems to be correct on these screenshots so this is strange behavior. Did you try to ship the order and see if it goes "out of stock" ?

Comment: Can you refresh the cache and check if it works?

Comment: @rpSetzer, @vrnet, The status changed automaticly after I went into System > Configuration > Inventory and saved it (without changed anything). Weird, weird weird.

Comment: @JohnT - ok, good to know. Thanks for the feedback and have fun Magentoing.

Answer (score 1):

The "Manage Stock" must be true either for the product itself or in the global configuration. See the Magento Wiki for more info: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/welcome_to_the_magento_user_s_guide/chapter_3#stock_management

Comment: hi, thank you for your answer, it is set to true. (I posted screenshot of my configuration)

Comment: Just a guess, but are you using AUTH or AUTH and CAPTURE? Perhaps the inventory doesn't decrement until the order has been invoiced?

Comment: all my product are set with a stock of 1 (unique product) so they get actually decremented because now it is set to 0

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a bug in Magento 1.4. As a workaround I run the following script every night via cron, to fix stock status of all products:

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_status')->rebuild();
```